# А во-вторых(,) потому что это ваше решение — мне доверять

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая?

> Ответственность за правильность этой работы я не несу, во-первых потому что меня не было на уроке, а во-вторых(,) потому что это ваше решение — мне доверять.